# Автоматизация создания скриншотов

Tags: юнит-тесты, тестирование, скрипт, автоматизация, скриншот

Друзья, всем привет! На работе задали задачку -- найти решение, с помощью которого можно автоматизировать создание скриншотов настольного приложения. Данное решение (допустим скрипт или программа) должно открывать все элементы интерфейса приложения (все окна, выпадающие списки, вкладки и т.д.) и скриншотить их. Может кто-нибудь знает программу которая такое умеет.
Сам просто не программист, пока что затрудняюсь.
Всем большое спасибо за помощь, друзья!

Answer (score 0):

добро пожаловать в десктоп-тестирование.
например, на python это может выглядеть так:
https://pyimagesearch.com/2018/01/01/taking-screenshots-with-opencv-and-python/

pyautogui нажимает на кнопки и управляет мышью. проверяет наличие элементов.

opencv делает скриншоты экрана